# JavaScript Strike Through innerText Not Working

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a To Do list and am having troubles <del>strikingthrough</del> a created To Do item. A "Click if Completed" button appears on the right side of the created to-do item which, when clicked, should strikeout the text. I am pretty sure it is an issue with the (e.target.newToDo.innerText.strike())

Do I need to create a variable for the newToDo.innerText? Am I still able to create one since I have created (newToDo.innerText = input.value) in the function earlier?

Just want to say that the people on this website are amazing and have helped a ton. Thank you in advance!

```js
const form = document.querySelector('#addToDo');
const input = document.querySelector('#theToDo');
const todolist = document.querySelector('#todolist');

form.addEventListener('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const newToDo = document.createElement('li');
    const removeBtn = document.createElement('button');
    const completeBtn = document.createElement('button');
    newToDo.innerText = input.value;
    removeBtn.innerText = 'Click to Remove';
    completeBtn.innerText = 'Click if Completed';
    newToDo.appendChild(completeBtn);
    newToDo.appendChild(removeBtn);
    input.value = '';
    todolist.appendChild(newToDo);

    completeBtn.addEventListener("click", function(e){
        e.target.newToDo.innerText.strike();
    })

    removeBtn.addEventListener("click", function(e){
        e.target.parentElement.remove();
    })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
     <h1>To Do List:</h1>
     <ul id="todolist">
        </ul>
     <form action="" id="addToDo" name="addToDo">
        <input type="text" id="theToDo" 
        name="addToDo" 
        placeholder="Add to the list here">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>    
    <script src=Test.js></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why wasn't your code working

Your code wasn't working because of `e.target.newToDo.innerText.strike()` this does not target the `li` (parent element) and you need to set the `innerText` to the striked `innerText` or it will not show.

### Why you should not use `strike()`

It is not good practice to edit styles within JS and the `<strike>` tag is not supported in HTML5.

Instead, create a CSS class like this:

```css
.strike {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Then append the `.strike` class to the HTML element.

### Solution

```js
const form = document.querySelector('#addToDo');
const input = document.querySelector('#theToDo');
const todolist = document.querySelector('#todolist');

form.addEventListener('submit',function(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  
  todolist.innerHTML += `<li>
                           <span>${input.value}</span>
                           <button onclick="strikeItem(this)">strike</button>
                           <button onclick="removeItem(this)">remove</button>
                         </li>`
})

function strikeItem(ele) {
  const itemTextEle = ele.parentElement.querySelector('span')
  
  itemTextEle.innerHTML = itemTextEle.innerText.strike()
}

function removeItem(ele) {
  ele.parentElement.remove()
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
     <h1>To Do List:</h1>
     <ul id="todolist">
        </ul>
     <form action="" id="addToDo" name="addToDo">
        <input type="text" id="theToDo" 
        name="addToDo" 
        placeholder="Add to the list here">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>    
    <script src=Test.js></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

This is a bit easier to read and is less code to write.

**This solution uses the `strike()` function to show you how to use it I would try appending a class instead.**

Answer (score 1):

Append your newToDo to todolist and change the innerHtml on click function call:

```
const form = document.querySelector('#addToDo');
const input = document.querySelector('#theToDo');
const todolist = document.querySelector('#todolist');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const newToDo = document.createElement('li');
  const removeBtn = document.createElement('button');
  const completeBtn = document.createElement('button');
  newToDo.id = 'new_todo';
  newToDo.innerText = input.value;
  removeBtn.innerText = 'Click to Remove';
  completeBtn.innerText = 'Click if Completed';
  todolist.append(newToDo);
  todolist.appendChild(completeBtn);
  todolist.appendChild(removeBtn);
  input.value = '';

  completeBtn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var todo = document.querySelector('#new_todo');
    var todoText = '<del>' + todo.innerText + '</del>';
    todo.innerHTML = todoText;
  })

  removeBtn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.target.parentElement.remove();
  })
})
```

see the working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/khushboo097/uak3f5s2/20/

Comment: This works great! However when I add multiple to do items and click one of the remove buttons, the entire list disappears. I don't understand why this happens since the e.target.parentElement.remove() should only be removing the li that the button is in right? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

```js
const form = document.querySelector('#addToDo');
const input = document.querySelector('#theToDo');
const todolist = document.querySelector('#todolist');

form.addEventListener('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const newToDo = document.createElement('li');
    const removeBtn = document.createElement('button');
    const completeBtn = document.createElement('button');
    newToDo.innerText = input.value;
    removeBtn.innerText = 'Click to Remove';
    completeBtn.innerText = 'Click if Completed';
    newToDo.appendChild(completeBtn);
    newToDo.appendChild(removeBtn);
    input.value = '';
    todolist.appendChild(newToDo);

    completeBtn.addEventListener("click", function(e){
        e.target.parentElement.style.textDecoration="line-through";
    })

    removeBtn.addEventListener("click", function(e){
        e.target.parentElement.remove();
    })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
     <h1>To Do List:</h1>
     <ul id="todolist">
        </ul>
     <form action="" id="addToDo" name="addToDo">
        <input type="text" id="theToDo" 
        name="addToDo" 
        placeholder="Add to the list here">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>    
    <script src=Test.js></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This does not strike off the text as per OP requirements

Comment: You should add a CSS class for striking it, instead of modifying it in Javascript

Comment: It is added to the styling of parent, it can be replaced with css class that has that specific styling.

Comment: Thank you devd! I should have clarified though. When I click the Click if completed button, the text is strikedthrough, however both buttons disappear. I would like to keep at least the "remove" button. If we are using the innerHTML function, would I need to recreate this "remove" button?

Comment: Working fine in the code snippet above, none of the buttons disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```js
const form = document.querySelector('#addToDo');
const input = document.querySelector('#theToDo');
const todolist = document.querySelector('#todolist');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const newToDo = document.createElement('li');
  const newToDoName = document.createElement('span');
  const removeBtn = document.createElement('button');
  const completeBtn = document.createElement('button');
  newToDoName.innerText = input.value;
  removeBtn.innerText = 'Click to Remove';
  completeBtn.innerText = 'Click if Completed';
  newToDo.appendChild(newToDoName);
  newToDo.appendChild(completeBtn);
  newToDo.appendChild(removeBtn);
  input.value = '';
  todolist.appendChild(newToDo);

  completeBtn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    newToDo.innerHTML = newToDoName.innerText.strike();
  })

  removeBtn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.target.parentElement.remove();
  })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>To Do List:</h1>
  <ul id="todolist">
  </ul>
  <form action="" id="addToDo" name="addToDo">
    <input type="text" id="theToDo" name="addToDo" placeholder="Add to the list here">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <script src=Test.js></script>
</body>

</html>
```